# Migrate AutoML translation's custom model to another GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-translation-api

I have some custom models for Google AutoML Translations trained in a QA GCP project.
I want to promote the models to production but I don't find a way to export/migrate the models from  QA to the PROD project.
Is it possible that the only solution is to train again from scratch models? I want to avoid this solution because the training sets are exactly the same between QA and PROD and the training process is not cheap.

Thank you in advance to anyone who will help to figure out a possible solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both projects are in the same organization? By train from scratch you mean Import prepared data from QA project to PROD project and then Train on the Product project? I never tried it so I will try to export/migrate ML Custom model and import in another project. Maybe its possible to export using GCS

Comment: Yes, both projects are in the same organization but one is used for QA and one for PROD. In the documentation is not mentioned the possibility to extract the trained models but I don't understand why they force you to train the models from scratch if the dataset used to train the model are the same.

Comment: I tried to do what you want but I couldn't find that option. There is also nothing in docs so I think it's impossible. It's possible to import a custom model using [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai) but I guess it's not an option. I think the only thing you can do is to create `Feature Request` on [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) to evaluate this functionality of importing custom models in Cloud Translation API.

Comment: Many thank PjoterS for your time, I will follow your advice.